# Asignación de valores 1 a 1 a partir de un foreach anidado

Tags: c#

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo distintos servicios y distintas solicitudes y requiero asignar un servicio con una solicitud, sin que el servicio se asigne a otra solicitud o viceversa que la solicitud sea asignada con otros servicios, en resumen que la relación sea 1 a 1.

Hasta ahora solo llevo lo siguiente tengo dos listas con 2 Servicios y 1 solicitud, aunque tambien podria tener 1 servicio con 10 solicitudes o 10 servicios con 1 solicitud;

```
public void TestMethod1() {

  Dictionary<Guid, Guid> servicioConSolicitud = new Dictionary<Guid, Guid>();

  List<Guid> servicios = new List<Guid>() {
    Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"),
    Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002")
  };

  List<Guid> solicitudes = new List<Guid>(){  
    Guid.Parse("2C13ACAF-9A8C-44E0-9140-8AFB33B147A0") 
  };

  foreach (Guid servicio in servicios){
    foreach (var solicitud in solicitudes){
      servicioConSolicitud.Add(servicio, solicitud);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes dar más detalles ?? Porque supongo que hay algo de fondo más allá de lo que has comentado

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo real para que se te pueda entender, da más detalles